# Wordpress: Membership plugin Ajax conflict with theme

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I recently installed the great WordPress plugin Armember, because I need some type of post restriction on my site, and Armeber is great.

Unfortunately, I ran into some problems.

One of the biggest problems is that my theme (Publisher) somehow conflicts with the Armember plugin. Everything that has something to do with Jquery or Ajax, doesn't work when my membership plugin is activated.

The second problem, is that Armember overrides some of the stylings from my theme, and I want the two to be separated so that my theme still looks like before, and everything that has to do with Armember looks like the Armember styling.

I am not the biggest coder, but I like to work with Wordpress. Can someone please give me an answer on what to do?

Thanks in advance!

- Victor

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some code where you think the problem is or post the errors you are seeing. Currently this question is not clear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this it maybe help you.

```
function my_init() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

}
add_action('init', 'my_init');

Comment: Where should i add it? Sorry, im not the biggets coder :/

Comment: please add your script enqueue name at 'jquery'.
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

Comment: I dont know what me script enqueue name is.

Comment: Show me your themes function file.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XSjoMuapYvXPRX8dvF2rOdA66mCkV7jppTSVbMtb6f4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please show me your header file? your functions file is looks perfect.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XSjoMuapYvXPRX8dvF2rOdA66mCkV7jppTSVbMtb6f4/edit?usp=sharing